# jquery disable not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails application. On the index.html.haml , I am also rendering the _form.html.haml (for new and edit actions.) There is a link "Add Group" on the index page which when clicked should disable certain fields in the form. I have written the jquery code for it. My problem is that when I click the link, the fields are disabled(grayed out) but instantly get enabled back again. If I refresh the page then I see the disabled fields. I want it to happen when I click the link and then stay disabled.

**jQuery Code**

```
$(function(){
    $("#add_requirement_group").click(function() {
        $("#requirement_text_full, #requirement_requirement_type").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

**Form for New and Edit actions.**

```
= form_for ([@requirement.requirements_template, @requirement]), html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  - if @requirement.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@requirement.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this requirement from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @requirement.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg   %fieldset
    .control-group
      = f.hidden_field :parent_id
    .control-group
      = f.label :text_brief, class: "control-label"
      .controls
        = f.text_field(:text_brief, class: "input-block-level")
    .control-group
      = f.label :text_full, class: "control-label"
      .controls
        = f.text_area(:text_full, rows: 5, class: "input-block-level")
    .control-group
      = f.label :obligation, class: "control-label"
    .control-group
      = f.label :requirement_type, class: "control-label"
      .controls
        = f.select :requirement_type, options_for_select([:text, :numeric, :date, :enum]), include_blank: true
      .actions.pull-right
    %br/
    = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-info'
    = button_to 'Finish', '#', class: 'btn btn-info', method: :get
```

**index.html.haml**

```
%hr
.row-fluid
  .span4
    %fieldset.template_outline
      %strong Template Outline
      %br
      = link_to 'Add Group', new_requirements_template_requirement_path(@requirements_template), id: "add_requirement_group"
      %hr
       = render 'form'
```

I know it is such a simple piece of code but for some reason the disable isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. When the "Add Group" link is clicked, the click event handler will fire, which will disable the HTML controls, as you expect. However, it will go ahead and do a redirect to "new_requirements_tempate_reqquirement_path", which I don't think you want it to do. In order to suppress the default action of the DOM element, you might want use "preventDefault().

```
$(function(){
    $("#add_requirement_group").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#requirement_text_full, #requirement_requirement_type").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

The behavior you are describing tells me you are using Turbo-Links, which ships standard on Rails 4.

Comment: Hi, it worked! Thank u so much. However a quick question. What do you mean when you say "In order to suppress the default action of the DOM element" in this case?

Comment: Never mind figured out what you meant. Thank u again.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate it if you could mark mine as an answer. Thanks. :)